# MySqli prepared statement not getting result from database

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using MySQLi Prepared statements using PHP.

The code I have written is:

```
<?php
  function mySQLi_connection(){
    $hostName = "localhost";
    $userName = "admin";
    $password = "admin";
    $databaseName = "db_name";
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostName, $userName, $password, $databaseName);
    if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    return $mysqli;
}


function getEmpNamebyID($id){
    $empname = NULL;
    $mysqli = mySQLi_connection();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `empname` FROM `employee_details` WHERE `EMP_ID` =?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($empname);
    echo $empname;
    return $empname;

}

echo getEmpNamebyID(95);
?>
```

The function `getEmpNamebyID()` DOES NOT return any result from the database. Even though the query is OK with the value `95`.

I wonder if there is anything wrong with my Prepare Statements. The Connection is working fine.

Comment: You have an extra condition, `if ($stmt2 = $mysqli ->prepare($qry))` which makes all other conditions quite useless. Better yet, get rid of all the conditions at all, by using the approach from the linked answer

Comment: besides, with your code you are connecting every time you are executing a query. this is a big no-no

Comment: Either there is anything wrong with your prepared statement and in this case you will have an error message. Or there is simply no such record to be found. there are no other possibilities

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have modified my code. My issue is not of getting any fatal errors. It's just not working at all. Nothing is being displayed on screen.

Comment: you forgot to fetch()

Comment: Yes. I forgot to fetch(). Thank You!